# Reversing String in C for loop error

Tags: c, c-strings

I have an array of strings and am trying to reverse each string in the array to see if that string is a palindrome. I am using a `for` loop to increment an `int i` (the index). However after the I call the reverse function, the value of `i` becomes some really large number and I cant figure out why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revString(char *dest, const char *source);

int main() {    
    const char *strs[] = {
        "racecar",
        "radar",
        "hello",
        "world"
    };

    int i;
    char res[] = "";
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(*strs); i++) {
        printf("i is %d\n", i);
        revString(&res[0], strs[i]); //reversing string
        printf("i is now %d\n", i); 

        //comparing string and reversed string  
        if (strcmp(res, strs[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Is a palindrome");
        } else {
            printf("Not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void revString(char *dest, const char *source) {
    printf("%s\n", source);
    int len = strlen(source);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    const char *p;
    char s;
    for (p = (source + (len - 1)); p >= source; p--) {
        s = *p;
        *(dest) = s; 
        dest += 1;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

This is the output showing the value of `i` before and after the `revString` function is called.

```
i is 0
i is now 1667588961
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Comment: regarding `i < strlen(*strs)`: you probably want to compute the `strlen()` before the loop.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Only functions. And none of the functions are methods.

Comment: `char res[] = "";` make for a _very small_ place to store a reversed string Only 1 `char` long`.

Comment: @AndrewJenkins Good point, but "i" is still jumping to a really large value

Comment: @chux I specified a length for res and that worked! Thanks

Comment: @srsxyz That completely fixed it? Don't you want `i<strlen(strs)` and not `i<strlen(*strs)`? Test: http://rextester.com/RFA16325

Comment: As ou are not reserving enough space for the reverse string, you are writing into arbitrary locations on your stack - most likely you overwrite  `i` in the process.

Comment: @DigitalNinja When i did i<strlen(strs), I got the following warning "incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *[4]' to parameter of type 'const char *'"

Comment: The for loop does not make sense. You calculate strlen for the first string and loop over the length while you use it as index. What you want is probably `i<(sizeof(strs)/sizeof(strs[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You pass a destination array `char res[] = "";` that is much too small for the strings you want to reverse. It's size is `1`. This causes buffer overflow, resulting in undefined behavior.

  Use `char res[20];` instead.
- You enumerate the array of string with an incorrect upper bound. Use this instead:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(strs) / sizeof(*strs); i++)
  ```
- The termination test for the loop in `revString()` is incorrect too: decrementing `p` when is equal to `source` has undefined behavior, although it is unlikely to have an consequences.  You can simplify this function this way:

  ```
  void revString(char *dest, const char *source) {
      size_t len = strlen(source);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          dest[i] = source[len - i - 1];
      }
      dest[len] = '\0';
  }
  ```

Here is the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revString(char *dest, const char *source) {
    size_t len = strlen(source);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[len - i - 1];
    }
    dest[len] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    const char *strs[] = { "racecar", "radar", "hello", "world" };
    char res[20];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(strs) / sizeof(*strs); i++) {
        revString(res, strs[i]);
        //comparing string and reversed string  
        if (strcmp(res, strs[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Is a palindrome\n");
        } else {
            printf("Not a palindrome\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Final Code with some change

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revString(char* dest, const char* source);
int main(){
    const char* strs[] = {
        "racecar",
        "radar",
        "hello",
        "world"
    };

    static int i;
    char res[] = "";
    int length = (int) sizeof(strs)/sizeof(char*);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("i is %d\n", i);
        revString(&res[0], strs[i]); //reversing string
        printf("i is now %d\n", i);

        //comparing string and reversed string
        if(strcmp(res, strs[i]) == 0){
            printf("Is a palindrome");
        }else{
            printf("Not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void revString(char* dest, const char* source){
    printf("%s\n", source);
    int len = (int) strlen(source);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    const char* p;
    char s;
    for(p = (source + (len - 1)); p >= source; p--){
        s = *p;
        *(dest) = s; 
        dest += 1;
    }
    *dest = '\0';

}
```

**Change 1 :-**

> int i; to static int i; (Reason:- i is local variable you are calling
>   function so when function call the value of i will remove and after
>   that it will assign garbage value.)

**change 2 :-**

> strlen(*strs) to length of array (because strlen(*strs) will give the
>   length of first string)

Comment: `static int i;`: absolutely not!

Comment: Why not? @chqrlie

Comment: Giving local variable `i` `static` storage does not fix the problem. It may hide it in some circumstances, but it does not correct the fact that the array `res[]` is too short.  Furthermore, it is bad advice to let the OP believe local `static` variables are harmless.  This construction should be reserved for cases where it is necessary and an API change is not possible or would not suffice.  The problems with `strtok()` are rooted in this usage, avoid it whenever possible.